# Hibernate one to many mapping error - mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property error

Tags: database, hibernate, mapping, one-to-many, schemaexport

I am trying to test one to many mapping by creating tables from domain objects  but I see the error **mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property**. Could some one take a look please?

Thanks

**Employee.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;  
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "employeetype", discriminatorType    
=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "Employee")
public abstract class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status")
private EmployeeStatus status;

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@Column(name = "hireDate")
private DateTime hireDate;

/**
 * @return the hireDate
 */
public DateTime getHireDate() {
    return hireDate;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @return the Status
 */
public EmployeeStatus getStatus() {
    return status;
}

/**
 * @param hireDate
 *            the hireDate to set
 */
public void setHireDate(final DateTime hireDate) {
    this.hireDate = hireDate;
}

/**
 * @param id
 *            the id to set
 */
public void setId(final int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @param name
 *            the name to set
 */
public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @param status
 *            the status to set
 */
public void setStatus(final EmployeeStatus status) {
    this.status = status;
}

}
```

**FulltimeEmployee.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("FulltimeEmployee")
@Table(name = "FulltimeEmployee")
public class FulltimeEmployee extends Employee {

@Column(name = "cubeNumber")
private String cubeNumber;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private FlightBenefit flightBenefit;

/**
 * @return the cubeNumber
 */
public String getCubeNumber() {
    return cubeNumber;
}

/**
 * @return the flightBenefit
 */
public FlightBenefit getFlightBenefit() {
    return flightBenefit;
}

/**
 * @param cubeNumber
 *            the cubeNumber to set
 */
public void setCubeNumber(final String cubeNumber) {
    this.cubeNumber = cubeNumber;
}

/**
 * @param flightBenefit
 *            the flightBenefit to set
 */
public void setFlightBenefit(final FlightBenefit flightBenefit) {
    this.flightBenefit = flightBenefit;
}

}
```

**ContractEmployee.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ContractEmployee")
@Table(name = "ContractEmployee")
public class ContractEmployee extends Employee {

@Column(name = "openAreaNumber")
private String openAreaNumber;

/**
 * @return the openAreaNumber
 */
public String getOpenAreaNumber() {
    return openAreaNumber;
}

/**
 * @param openAreaNumber
 *            the openAreaNumber to set
 */
public void setOpenAreaNumber(final String openAreaNumber) {
    this.openAreaNumber = openAreaNumber;
}

}
```

**FlightBenefit.java**

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;


@Entity
@Table(name = "FlightBenefit")
public class FlightBenefit {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@Column(name = "useByTime")
private DateTime useByTime;

@Column(name = "discountAmount")
private String discountAmount;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "FlightBenefit")
private Set&lt;FulltimeEmployee&gt; FulltimeEmployees;

/**
 * @return the discountAmount
 */
public String getDiscountAmount() {
    return discountAmount;
}

/**
 * @return the fulltimeEmployees
 */
public Set&lt;FulltimeEmployee&gt; getFulltimeEmployees() {
    return FulltimeEmployees;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @return the useByTime
 */
public DateTime getUseByTime() {
    return useByTime;
}

/**
 * @param discountAmount
 *            the discountAmount to set
 */
public void setDiscountAmount(final String discountAmount) {
    this.discountAmount = discountAmount;
}

/**
 * @param fulltimeEmployees
 *            the fulltimeEmployees to set
 */
public void setFulltimeEmployees(final Set&lt;FulltimeEmployee&gt; fulltimeEmployees) {
    FulltimeEmployees = fulltimeEmployees;
}

/**
 * @param id
 *            the id to set
 */
public void setId(final String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @param useByTime
 *            the useByTime to set
 */
public void setUseByTime(final DateTime useByTime) {
    this.useByTime = useByTime;
}

}
```

**EmployeeStatus**

```
public enum EmployeeStatus {

ACTIVE,

INACTIVE

}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
 !DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"
hibernate-configuration
 session-factory
property name="connection.driver_class"&gt;com.mysql.jdbc.Driver&lt;/property
property    
name="connection.url"&gt;jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB&lt;/property
property name="connection.username"&gt;user&lt;/property
property name="connection.password"&gt;password123&lt;/property
property name="show_sql"&gt;true&lt;/property
property name="dialect"&gt;org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect&lt;/property
property name="hibernate.default_schema"&gt;TestSchema&lt;/property
!--    &lt;property name="hbm2ddl.auto"&gt;validate&lt;/property&gt; --
/session-factory&
/hibernate-configuration&


**Main.java**



import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;


public class Main {

public static void main(final String args[]) {

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(ContractEmployee.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(FulltimeEmployee.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(FlightBenefit.class);

    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    SchemaExport se = new SchemaExport(config);
    se.execute(true, true, false, true);

    SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    ContractEmployee cEmployee = new ContractEmployee();
    cEmployee.setName("Raj");
    cEmployee.setStatus(EmployeeStatus.ACTIVE);
    cEmployee.setHireDate(DateTime.now());
    cEmployee.setOpenAreaNumber("421a29");
    session.save(cEmployee);

    FlightBenefit flightbenefit = new FlightBenefit();
    flightbenefit.setDiscountAmount("1000");
    flightbenefit.setUseByTime(DateTime.now());

    FulltimeEmployee fEmployee = new FulltimeEmployee();
    fEmployee.setName("Teja");
    fEmployee.setStatus(EmployeeStatus.INACTIVE);
    fEmployee.setHireDate(DateTime.now());
    fEmployee.setCubeNumber("Cube 19");
    fEmployee.setFlightBenefit(flightbenefit);
    session.save(fEmployee);

    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}
}
```

**Error StackTrace**

```
Jun 1, 2013 2:21:14 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version &lt;clinit&gt;
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Jun 1, 2013 2:21:14 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
Jun 1, 2013 2:21:14 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment &lt;clinit&gt;
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jun 1, 2013 2:21:14 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jun 1, 2013 2:21:14 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Jun 1, 2013 2:21:14 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Jun 1, 2013 2:21:14 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Jun 1, 2013 2:21:14 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect &lt;init&gt;
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jun 1, 2013 2:21:15 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy:     
ContractEmployee
Jun 1, 2013 2:21:15 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy:    
FulltimeEmployee
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an     
unknown target entity property: FulltimeEmployee.FlightBenefit in   
FlightBenefit.FulltimeEmployees at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:708)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:668)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1611)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1369)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateDropSchemaScript(Configuration.java:941)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.&lt;init&gt;(SchemaExport.java:188)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.&lt;init&gt;(SchemaExport.java:156)
at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

---

Thanks for ur reply. I made the changes you have mentioned and also made few other changes like adding **session.save(flightBenefit)** to Main.java and **insertable =  false, updatable = false** with @JoinColumn annotation. I see Employee table being created but not FlightBenefit and am seeing the error

Caused by: **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'TestSchema.flightbenefit' doesn't exist**

Below are the classes with updated changes and stacktrace

**Main.java**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;


public class Main {

public static void main(final String args[]) {

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(ContractEmployee.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(FulltimeEmployee.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(FlightBenefit.class);
    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    SchemaExport se = new SchemaExport(config);
    se.execute(true, true, false, true);

    SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    FlightBenefit flightbenefit = new FlightBenefit();
    flightbenefit.setDiscountAmount("1000");
    flightbenefit.setUseByTime(DateTime.now());
    session.save(flightbenefit);

    ContractEmployee cEmployee = new ContractEmployee();
    cEmployee.setName("Raj");
    cEmployee.setStatus(EmployeeStatus.ACTIVE);
    cEmployee.setHireDate(DateTime.now());
    cEmployee.setOpenAreaNumber("421a29");
    session.save(cEmployee);



    FulltimeEmployee fEmployee = new FulltimeEmployee();
    fEmployee.setName("Teja");
    fEmployee.setStatus(EmployeeStatus.INACTIVE);
    fEmployee.setHireDate(DateTime.now());
    fEmployee.setCubeNumber("Cube 19");
    fEmployee.setFlightBenefit(flightbenefit);
    session.save(fEmployee);

    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}
}
```

**FulltimeEmployee.Java**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("FulltimeEmployee")
public class FulltimeEmployee extends Employee {

@Column(name = "cubeNumber")
private String cubeNumber;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable =  false, updatable = false)
private FlightBenefit flightBenefit;

/**
 * @return the cubeNumber
 */
public String getCubeNumber() {
    return cubeNumber;
}

/**
 * @return the flightBenefit
 */
public FlightBenefit getFlightBenefit() {
    return flightBenefit;
}

/**
 * @param cubeNumber
 *            the cubeNumber to set
 */
public void setCubeNumber(final String cubeNumber) {
    this.cubeNumber = cubeNumber;
}

/**
 * @param flightBenefit
 *            the flightBenefit to set
 */
public void setFlightBenefit(final FlightBenefit flightBenefit) {
    this.flightBenefit = flightBenefit;
}

}
```

**FlightBenefit.java**

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;


@Entity
@Table(name = "FlightBenefit")
public class FlightBenefit {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@Column(name = "useByTime")
private DateTime useByTime;

@Column(name = "discountAmount")
private String discountAmount;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "flightBenefit")
private Set<FulltimeEmployee> FulltimeEmployees;

/**
 * @return the discountAmount
 */
public String getDiscountAmount() {
    return discountAmount;
}

/**
 * @return the fulltimeEmployees
 */
public Set<FulltimeEmployee> getFulltimeEmployees() {
    return FulltimeEmployees;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @return the useByTime
 */
public DateTime getUseByTime() {
    return useByTime;
}

/**
 * @param discountAmount
 *            the discountAmount to set
 */
public void setDiscountAmount(final String discountAmount) {
    this.discountAmount = discountAmount;
}

/**
 * @param fulltimeEmployees
 *            the fulltimeEmployees to set
 */
public void setFulltimeEmployees(final Set<FulltimeEmployee> fulltimeEmployees) {
    FulltimeEmployees = fulltimeEmployees;
}

/**
 * @param id
 *            the id to set
 */
public void setId(final String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @param useByTime
 *            the useByTime to set
 */
public void setUseByTime(final DateTime useByTime) {
    this.useByTime = useByTime;
}

}
```

**StackTrace**

```
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:18 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:18 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:18 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:18 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:18 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:18 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:19 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:19 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:21 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:21 PM     
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl   
configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:21 PM 
 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl 
 configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:21 PM     
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl   
 configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:21 PM  
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl 
configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL    
[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestSchema]
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:21 PM   
 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl   
 configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=user, password=****}

create table TestSchema.Employee (
    employeetype varchar(31) not null,
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    hireDate datetime,
    name varchar(255),
    status varchar(255),
    openAreaNumber varchar(255),
    cubeNumber varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
)

create table TestSchema.FlightBenefit (
    id varchar(255) not null auto_increment,
    discountAmount varchar(255),
    useByTime datetime,
    primary key (id)
)
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table TestSchema.FlightBenefit (id varchar(255)     
not null auto_increment, discountAmount varchar(255), useByTime datetime, primary key  
(id))
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'

alter table TestSchema.Employee 
    add index FK_opia9u461cgfe5i9vk7bo0p56 (id), 
    add constraint FK_opia9u461cgfe5i9vk7bo0p56 
    foreign key (id) 
    references TestSchema.FlightBenefit (id)
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table TestSchema.Employee add index   
FK_opia9u461cgfe5i9vk7bo0p56 (id), add constraint FK_opia9u461cgfe5i9vk7bo0p56 foreign   
 key (id) references TestSchema.FlightBenefit (id)
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Cannot add foreign key constraint
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM   
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  
stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestSchema]
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM   
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl 
configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)

Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM  

org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl 
 configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM     
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl 
configure

 INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
 Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM   
 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  
 configure
 INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL    
[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestSchema]
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM  
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl 
configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=user, password=****}
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM   
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:23 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: insert into TestSchema.FlightBenefit (discountAmount, useByTime) values (?,   
?)
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Jun 1, 2013 2:18:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'TestSchema.flightbenefit' doesn't exist
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not    
execute statement
at 
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.
    convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.
    convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.
   convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.
   convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.   
     executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
at 
org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.
executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.
 performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.
 insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2975)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.
  insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3487)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.
  execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.
     addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:194)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:178)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.
   addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.
   performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.
      performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.
      saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.
     saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.
  saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.
  entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.
   performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.
   onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
at Main.main(Main.java:34)
   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table     
 'TestSchema.flightbenefit' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
at   

 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.
 executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
... 22 more
```

Answer (score 4):

**Answer to original question:**

Following is incorrect, because `FulltimeEmployee` does not have persistent attribute named `FlightBenefit`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "FlightBenefit")
private Set<FulltimeEmployee> FulltimeEmployees;
```

Names of persistent attributes are case sensitive. Because attribute is `flightBenefit` (first character is lower case), name should be exactly same when used in mappedBy:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "flightBenefit")
```

Additionally as warnings are telling, using Table annotation in subclass does not make sense with SINGLE_TABLE: they are persisted to single table so consequently table is same.

**Answer to question after modification:**

Now problem comes from:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;
```

That does not work, because there is no auto increment for String (varchar in database). That was also told in logs in following message: *Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'*. When feasible, use Integer/Long instead.