# not saving child entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In a spring mvc project using hibernate and jpa, I am have a `person` entity, and a `role` entity.  Each `person` can have many `roles`, but each `role` can only have one `person`.  How can I save a new `role` for an existing `person`?

I have read many postings on this.  If I try to save the new `role`, I get an error about not being able to save a detached entity.  But if I try to save the existing `person`, the role does not get saved.  I read [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist/13370397?noredirect=1#comment42271783_13370397) suggesting that the hibernate annotations should be moved to the getters, but when I do that, I get a hibernate mapping error referencing an unknown property.  And [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871012/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-error-mappedby-reference-an-unknown-target-entit) says the resolution of the new error is to move the annotations back to the getters, without mentioning that results in the detached entity error.  The various stack overflow questions thus seem to point in a circle.  **So how can I fix my code to actually save the new child entity?**

Here is the Person:

```
@Entity(name = "RimPerson")
@Table(name = "rim_person")
public class RimPerson {

    @Id
    @Column(name="hppid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "native")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private Long hppid;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = RimRole.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL
    }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_rimperson_HJID")
    private List<RimRole> playedRoles;

    //other properties and getters and setters
}
```

Role is:

```
@Entity(name = "RimRole")
@Table(name = "rim_role")
public class RimRole {

    @Id
    @Column(name="hppid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "native")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private Long hppid;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = RimPerson.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL
    }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_rimperson_HJID", nullable=true)
    private RimPerson player;  

    //other stuff and getters and setters

}
```

Here is the JPQL in the repository layer:

```
@Override
public void saveRIMPerson(RimPerson myperson) throws DataAccessException{
    if (myperson.getHppid() == null) {this.em.persist(myperson);}
    else {this.em.merge(myperson);}
}
```

The complete code for the relevant classes can be found [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/b/XYRRAn5kdqzvr8g2zO7e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bi-directional one-to-many relationship between entities `RimPerson` and `RimRole`. So you need to tell hibernate which is the owner of association using the `mappedBy` attribute, in case of `one-to-many` relationship the `many` side is considered as owner of association, so in `RimPerson` the mapping should be like this:

```
 @OneToMany(targetEntity = RimRole.class, mappedBy="player", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL
    }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<RimRole> playedRoles;
```

Note that we have to remove the `@JoinColumn` annotation from here. Also the value of mappedBy attribute should match with the property name that you have defined in `RimRole` which is `player`.

Now for a bi-directional association you need to set the properties from both sides of entities, this means:

```
rimPerson.setPlayedRoles(playedRoles);
rimRole.setPlayer(player);
```

Try to update your code with these changes and run the application, this should fix the issue.

Comment: Your code triggered a new error before I can get to the point to test your code.  I will look into this again in 12 hours.  It is late here.  But the new error triggered by your code is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: RimPerson is not mapped [SELECT pers FROM RimPerson pers left join fetch pers.names WHERE pers.hppid =:id]`

Comment: The error says hibernate doesn't know what `RimPerson` is, this is not possible based on the explanation in your question. Please post your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, code that you have tried and complete stacktrace of exception once you have access to your machine at your day time, so I can check further.

Comment: +1 Thank you.  The follow up error was due to my having renamed the package in a way that made spring unable to find it unless a changed a config file.  Your suggestion helped me isolate that cause.  It works now.